# jquery fire event in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I keep event of change of select into dialog that don't fire?

my HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="dialog_message"></div>
    </body>
```

my JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var titolo = 'my dialog';
    var s="<select id=\"MYSEL1\" name=\"MYSEL1\"><option value=\"A\">opt A</option><option value=\"B\">opt B</option></select><br><select id=\"MYSEL2\" name=\"MYSEL2\"></select>";

    $( "#dialog_message" ).dialog({
        resize: 'auto',
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function() {      // open event handler
            $(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $(this).html(s);
        },
        buttons: {
            Annulla: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        title: titolo
    });
    $("select").selectmenu();
    $("#MYSEL1").on("change", function() {
        var n=$(this).attr("id");
        var dd = $("option:selected", this);
        var d = $(this).val();
        alert (d);  
        $("#MYSEL2").empty(); // remove old options
        if (d=='A') {
            $("#MYSEL2").append('<option value=\"AA\">opt AA</option><option value=\"AAA\">opt AAA</option>');
        } else {
            $("#MYSEL2").append('<option value=\"BB\">opt BB</option><option value=\"BBB\">opt BBB</option>');
        };
    });
```

You can find in jsfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/t0L915po/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the event to select element after the dialog box opens. Use the below code:

```
var titolo = 'my dialog';
var s="<select id=\"MYSEL1\" name=\"MYSEL1\"><option value=\"A\">opt A</option><option value=\"B\">opt B</option></select><br><select id=\"MYSEL2\" name=\"MYSEL2\"></select>";

$( "#dialog_message" ).dialog({
    resize: 'auto',
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function() {      // open event handler
        $(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        $(this).html(s);
        $("#MYSEL1").on("change", function() {
    var n=$(this).attr("id");
    var dd = $("option:selected", this);
    var d = $(this).val();
    alert (d);  
    $("#MYSEL2").empty(); // remove old options
    if (d=='A') {
        $("#MYSEL2").append('<option value=\"AA\">opt AA</option><option value=\"AAA\">opt AAA</option>');
    } else {
        $("#MYSEL2").append('<option value=\"BB\">opt BB</option><option value=\"BBB\">opt BBB</option>');
    };
}); 
    },
    buttons: {
        Annulla: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    title: titolo
});
$("select").selectmenu();
```

Comment: I just ran this code on JSFiddle and saw it  is running and showing the alert and also changing the second select drop down values

Comment: You are welcome. If the solution work please accept the answer so that it helps other also with this similar kind of problem.

Comment: Do not work using JqueryUI 1.11.4 (Work fine with 1.10.3).